# Problem with multiple URLs provided in mendeley

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle, mendeley

So I have a mendeley profile in which I created the bib file for my thesis. For multiple papers i provided multiple URLs (e.g. arxiv and a github repo).

When I cite a paper with multiple URLs the URL key in the bibliogrpahy is messed up. Specifically there is no space inbetween the 2 URLs and on top the link is not correct.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Sample for a bib entry:

```
@article{ControlNet,
    title = {{Adding Conditional Control to Text-to-Image Diffusion Models}},
    year = {2023},
    author = {Zhang, Lvmin and Rao, Anyi and Agrawala, Maneesh},
    month = {2},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2302.05543 https://github.com/lllyasviel/ControlNet},
    arxivId = {2302.05543}
}
```

biblatex setup:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

citation:

```
\cite{ControlNet}
```

results:
[image: Unseperated URLs and incorrect links]

============= EDIT

Adapted accordingly to the link provided in the comments:
github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/229#issuecomment-279766334

bibtex setup looks like:

```
%% Setup Bibliography
\usepackage[style=numeric, datamodel=urls]{biblatex}

\DeclareListFormat{urls}{%
  \url{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{url}{\iffieldundef{url}{\printlist{urls}}{\printfield{url}}}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

urls.dbx file:

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=uri]{urls}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{urls}
```

Problem still remaining - what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: url can hold only one url. If you want more you must define a new list field and change the bib macros so that they use it.  see  https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1304 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/229#issuecomment-279766334

Comment: In the second link you provided the urls.dbx is modified. Since I'm working on overleaf I can't edit any files except for the tex files. Or am I misunderstanding something.

Comment: urls.dbx is a file that you can create yourself.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer edited the question to have current state - problem still remains

Comment: Off-topic: it's wrong to use the `@article` entry type for the `ControlNet` entry. Just because Mendeley commits this form of reckless professional abuse does *not* make it right to mis-use BibTeX entry types. You may want to reconsider, though, whether it's a good idea to rely too heavily and unquestioningly on Mendeley... Please change the entry type to `@unpublished`.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the advise! Will change.

Comment: I can't test now but imho  you should separate the urls with the keyword and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works only for URLs devided by a space.

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,DIV=16,parskip=half-,fontsize=10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\begin{filecontents}[force,noheader]{\jobname.bib}
@article{ControlNet,
    title = {{Adding Conditional Control to Text-to-Image Diffusion Models}},
    year = {2023},
    author = {Zhang, Lvmin and Rao, Anyi and Agrawala, Maneesh},
    month = {2},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2302.05543 https://github.com/lllyasviel/ControlNet},
    arxivId = {2302.05543}
}\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\def\URLA#1 #2 #3!!{\url{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else, \url{#2}\fi
  \ifx\relax#3\relax \else, \URLA#3 !!\fi}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \mkbibacro{URL}(s)\addcolon\addspace
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\URLA\thefield{urlraw} !!}\x}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{ControlNet}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]